# Debugging mergesort

Tags: c, debugging, mergesort

I need to sort a doubly-linked list. According to the almighty wikipedia, mergesort is the way to go for that.

The recursive algorithm works reasonably well, but as I'm writing a general-purpose implementation, performance might be an issue.

Porting the iterative version for arrays will kill performance as rescanning the list to divide it into sublists is slow; for anyone interested - here's the code:

```
static void sort(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    size_t slice_size = 1;
    for(; slice_size < list->size; slice_size *= 2)
    {
        struct node *tail = list->first;
        while(tail)
        {
            struct node *head = tail;

            size_t count = slice_size;
            while(tail && count--) // performance killer
                tail = tail->next;

            count = slice_size;
            while(head != tail && tail && count)
            {
                if(cmp(head->data, tail->data) <= 0)
                    head = head->next;
                else
                {
                    struct node *node = tail;
                    tail = tail->next;
                    remove_node(node, list);
                    insert_before(node, list, head);
                    --count;
                }
            }

            while(tail && count--) // performance killer
                tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
}
```

But there's another iterative version using a stack-based approach:

```
struct slice
{
    struct node *head;
    size_t size;
};

static void sort(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if(list->size < 2) return;

    struct slice stack[32];
    size_t top = -1;
    struct node *current = list->first;

    for(; current; current = current->next)
    {
        stack[++top] = (struct slice){ current, 1 };
        for(; top && stack[top-1].size <= stack[top].size; --top)
            merge_down(list, cmp, stack + top);
    }

    for(; top; --top)
        merge_down(list, cmp, stack + top);
}
```

This will push size 1 lists onto the stack and merges down as long as the top list is of greater or equal size than its predecessor.

Unfortunately, there's a bug somewhere as for some input lists, `merge_down()` will fail a sanity check:

```
static void merge_down(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *), struct slice *top)
{
    struct node *right = top->head;
    size_t count = top->size;

    --top;

    struct node *left = top->head;
    top->size += count;

{
    // sanity check: count nodes in right list
    int i = count;
    struct node *node = right;
    for(; i--; node = node->next) if(!node)
    {
        puts("too few right nodes");
        exit(0);
    }
}

    // determine merged list's head
    if(cmp(left->data, right->data) <= 0)
    {
        top->head = left;
        left = left->next;
    }
    else
    {
        top->head = right;
        struct node *node = right;
        right = right->next;
        remove_node(node, list);
        insert_before(node, list, left);
        --count;
    }

    while(left != right && count)
    {
        if(cmp(left->data, right->data) <= 0)
            left = left->next;
        else
        {
            struct node *node = right;
            right = right->next;
            remove_node(node, list);
            insert_before(node, list, left);
            --count;
        }
    }
}
```

The linked list implementation might be relevant as well:

```
struct node
{
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    long long data[]; // use `long long` for alignment
};

struct linked_list
{
    struct _list _list; // ignore
    size_t size;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
};

static void insert_before(struct node *node, struct linked_list *list,
    struct node *ref_node)
{
    if(ref_node)
    {
        node->next = ref_node;
        node->prev = ref_node->prev;
        if(ref_node->prev) ref_node->prev->next = node;
        else list->first = node;
        ref_node->prev = node;
    }
    else // empty list
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    }
    ++list->size;
}

static void remove_node(struct node *node, struct linked_list *list)
{
    if(node->prev) node->prev->next = node->next;
    else list->first = node->next;
    if(node->next) node->next->prev = node->prev;
    else list->last = node->prev;
    --list->size;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: why don't you try a direct derecursival of your recursive version ? It's often more efficient (both for debugging and code performance) than trying to use a brand new iterative version. Derecursival is usually quite mechanical and do not requires much thinking. If you show us your recursive version we could see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error myself:

```
for(; current; current = current->next)
{
    stack[++top] = (struct slice){ current, 1 };
    for(; top && stack[top-1].size <= stack[top].size; --top)
        merge_down(list, cmp, stack + top);
}
```

Here, the next value of `current` gets determined **after** the call to `merge_down()`, which might move the node around, ie `current->next` will no longer point to the correct node.

Rearranging fixes the problem:

```
while(current)
{
    stack[++top] = (struct slice){ current, 1 };
    current = current->next;
    for(; top && stack[top-1].size <= stack[top].size; --top)
        merge_down(list, cmp, stack + top);
}
```

Thanks to pmg for the effort: I added some votes for that.

Comment: hm.. I'll have to wait two days befor being able to accept my own answer :(

Comment: YAY! Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever need to copy a node to the end of the list?
What's the `insert_before()` call then?

```
insert_before(node, list, NULL);
```

That would mess up `list->first` and `node->prev`.

Comment: I think such a call can't happen - I'll add some debug output to `insert_before()` to make sure...

Answer (score 1):

I've now run your code and got it to working after I commented out the line indicated below.

```
static void merge_down(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *), struct slice *top)
{
    struct node *right = top->head;
    size_t count = top->size;

    --top;

    struct node *left = top->head;
    top->size += count; /* possible bug? */
 /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```

Does that work for you too?

Comment: seems to work - but I don't understand why: as I'm merging the top 2 lists and discarding the right one, shouldn't the left list's size be increased by the right one's

Comment: doesn't work: I get an endless loop for large input sizes; easy fix is to add a check `&& right` to the loop condition instead, but I'd like to understand what't going wrong

Answer (score 0):

stack-based approach

```
/* ... */
    struct slice stack[32];
    size_t top = -1;
    struct node *current = list->first;

    for(; current; current = current->next)
    {
        stack[++top] = (struct slice){ current, 1 };
        for(; top && stack[top-1].size <= stack[top].size; --top)
        /*    ^^^    */
            merge_down(list, cmp, stack + top);
    }
/* ... */
```

`top` is always going to be 0 the first time through the loop, right?
The `merge_down()` function is never going to get called. I didn't try the code, but that doesn't look right.

---

*Edit*
32 elements for the `stack` is not enough... When the list has more than 32 elements in order (maybe after a few passes) you write beyond the end of `stack`.

Comment: afaik it's correct: you can only merge down if there are at leat two list on the stack, ie no merging on the first iteration

Comment: Check that `top` doesn't go over the limit: `assert (top < (sizeof stack / sizeof stack[0]) - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

As kriss asked for it, here's the recursive version (a standard mergesort using the merge function from the other exaples):

```
static struct node *merge(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *),
    struct node *left, struct node *right, size_t right_count)
{
    struct node *head;
    if(cmp(left->data, right->data) <= 0)
    {
        head = left;
        left = left->next;
    }
    else
    {
        head = right;
        struct node *node = right;
        right = right->next;
        remove_node(node, list);
        insert_before(node, list, left);
        --right_count;
    }

    while(left != right && right_count)
    {
        if(cmp(left->data, right->data) <= 0)
            left = left->next;
        else
        {
            struct node *node = right;
            right = right->next;
            remove_node(node, list);
            insert_before(node, list, left);
            --right_count;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

static struct node *mergesort(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *), struct node *head, size_t size)
{
    if(size < 2) return head;
    size_t left_count = size / 2;
    size_t right_count = size - left_count;

    struct node *tail = head;
    size_t count = left_count;
    while(count--) tail = tail->next;

    return merge(list, cmp,
        mergesort(list, cmp, head, left_count),
        mergesort(list, cmp, tail, right_count),
        right_count);
}

static void sort(struct linked_list *list,
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    mergesort(list, cmp, list->first, list->size);
}
```